# Quikly inverse two words in a long

Tags: vb.net, optimization, bit-manipulation

I have a integer value which, when some condition are met, must be modified like in this example :

```
00000001 10000000 11111111 00000000
```

becomes

```
11111111 00000000 00000001 10000000
```

The first 16 bit word must become the second and vice-vera. I know I can easily convert my long into a array of 0 and 1 and then I could use powers of 2 to reconstruct the long that I way I need it, but I was wondering is there was any other, better and faster way to do it. By faster I mean execution wise. If it's more complicated but have a better result, it's still fine with me.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with shifts and bitwise or:

```
value = (value << 16) | (value >> 16)
```

Comment: @JonSkeet Because it's signed? Unsigned should fix, no?

Comment: Yes. Then there's just the matter of `long` being 8 bytes, not 4... (which is the OP's problem, not yours really)

Comment: My bad, it's an integer, not a long.

Comment: @Pubby, it's not signed or anything. It's because I get it from an interface which read physical counter. On some machine, the guy switch edthe two and apparently he cannot 'unswitch' them.

Comment: I don't need to worry about the sign. If the result is negative it's because it's meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code I test the VB.NET version of Pubby's answer, `SwapMath`, against the explicit structure offset alternative, `SwapBits`. The former is about 40 times faster, probably partly because it is almost definitely in-lined.

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Diagnostics

Namespace Stackoverflow
Module SO13475894
  <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)> _
  Structure UShorts
    <FieldOffset(0)> Public x As UInteger
    <FieldOffset(0)> Public xLow  As UShort
    <FieldOffset(2)> Public xHigh As UShort
  End Structure

  Function SwapMath(ByVal x As UInteger) As UInteger
    Return (x >> 16) Or (x << 16)
  End Function

  ' About 40 times slower :-(
  Function SwapBits(ByVal x As UInteger) As UInteger
    Dim swapper As UShorts
    swapper.x = x
    Dim swapTemp = swapper.xLow
    swapper.xLow = swapper.xHigh
    swapper.xHigh = swapTemp
    Return swapper.x
  End Function

Sub Main()

  Dim x As UInteger = Convert.ToUInt32("11111111000000000000000110000000", fromBase:=2)

  Dim y = SwapMath(x)
  Dim z = SwapMath(y)
  Console.WriteLine(x)
  Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(y, toBase:=2))
  Console.WriteLine(z=x)

  y = SwapBits(x)
  z = SwapBits(y)
  Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(y, toBase:=2))
  Console.WriteLine(z=x)

  Const N As Integer = 100000000
  Dim sw = Stopwatch.StartNew

  For i = 1 To N
    y = SwapMath(x)
    z = SwapMath(y)
  Next
  sw.Stop
  Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds/CDbl(N))

  sw = Stopwatch.StartNew

  For i = 1 To N
    y = SwapBits(x)
    z = SwapBits(y)
  Next
  sw.Stop
  Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds/CDbl(N))

End Sub
End Module
End Namespace
```

Comment: BTW I used the opposite direction as a first test because that could have had sign issues, if I hadn't then used unsigned integers.